# set timeout for the first execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to retrieve new contents for a page each hour.

```
        (function worker() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/test.html', 
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.result').html(data);
                },
                complete: function() {
                  setTimeout(worker, 3600000);
                }
            });
        })();
```

It loads the content every 60 minutes but what I really whant is to load the new contents at the beginning of each hour (i.e. at 8:00 and then again at 9:00).
If I first load the page at the beginning of an hour my code is usefull but if I first load it during an hour (for example at 7:45) it reload contents at 8:45 and so on. How can I improve my code to say that the first time the reload should happen after 15 minutes and then at each hour? How do I change setTimeout function to achieve my goal? 
I have found a piece of code that can be close to my goal but I'm stucking my head on how to integrate it in my function:

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
 var now = new Date();
 var then = new Date();
 if(now.getHours() > hours ||
    (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
     now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes &&
     now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
     then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
 }
 then.setHours(hours);
 then.setMinutes(minutes);
 then.setSeconds(seconds);
 var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
 setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
 }
```

Comment: I would recomend using http://momentjs.com/. It provides functions like `startOf('hour')` which are less brittle than messing around with Date objects your self.

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I am looking for. The point is on integrating the two codes. Not on dealing with Date object.

Comment: Take a look at my answer for how to use it to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first timeout with the offset for the hour.

```
setTimeout(worker,3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000))
```

This will be somewhat accurate (Date object construction might take some milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

You can just calculate the remaining milliseconds till the next hour

```
function doNextHour(callback) {
    // time now in milliseconds since 1970
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var MS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    // remaining ms until next hour
    var remaining = MS_IN_HOUR - (now % MS_IN_HOUR);
    setTimeout(callback, remaining);
}
```

Use like

```
    (function worker() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/test.html', 
            success: function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
              doNextHour(worker);
            }
        });
    })();
```

Make sure you also call the `worker()` initially to start the cron job

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you will get current time's minutes by:

```
var date = new Date();

var minutes = date.getMinutes();
```

Now in your code, try something like:

```
if(minutes == 0){

         setTimeout(worker, 3600000);
}else{

        setTimeout(worker, 3600000-minutes*1000);

}
```

But make sure you get your contents for the first time, if minutes == 0.

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you

```
function worker() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/test.html', 
            success: function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
              setTimeout(worker, 3600000);
            }
        });
    }

var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
if(mins > 0){
  mins = 60 - mins;
}

setTimeout(worker, mins*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about recalculating the delay every loop:

```
(function worker() {
    var next_call = 60 - new Date().getMinutes();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html', 
        success: function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
          setTimeout(worker, next_call*60*1000);
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing with Date objects directly, I would use this library: http://momentjs.com/docs/

You then have something simple like this, which avoids writing custom date logic, and is easy to read:

```
var worker = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html', 
    success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(worker, moment().endOf('hour').valueOf());
    }
  });
};

setTimeout(worker, moment().endOf('hour').valueOf());
```